# Sync to an iPhone's Location Data?

Tags: ios, iphone, gps

I'm attempting to create a simple single-page website that answers the following yes or no question: is a specific iPhone on land?

To explain further, I want to track the iPhone of my brother who works on a tugboat to find out if he's on the boat or on land. Is there a way of syncing to his iPhone's GPS data? Perhaps through "Find my iPhone" or a similar app?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS you can access the GPS coordinate of a device using [CoreLocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/_index.html), specifically `CLLocationManager`. You can poll it for updates and you get back a `CLLocation` object that has your latitude/longitude. There may be another step you need to perform after this to see if a GPS point is on land or not, which I'm not exactly sure the best way to approach.

Comment: Thanks so much for that quick and informative answer. It's definitely helpful although my programming is limited to basic HTML/CSS/Javascript so I'm not sure if I'll be able to go this route. I wonder if there is a way to use the data outputted by an app such as [Find my Friends](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/find-my-friends/id466122094) so that the necessary programming can stay minimal?

Comment: Unless the app in question exports a data file that you can use, the answer is no. You'll need to program with Objective-C, or use a HTML5 app wrapper such as PhoneGap or Titanium in order to interact with location services using javascript.